# initWithFormat not making much sense after 2 hours?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Being the 'newbie' I have been staring at the 'documentation and api reference' docs for 2 hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and my eyeballs are now bleeding. The following code keeps throwing 'yellow triangle' warning in xcode 4. (Format not a string literal and no format arguments)

I really don't know what I am doing ... yet, but I would like to understand why and I getting this warning and how to make it go away. Thanks for any help.

```
-(IBAction)saveZip:(id)sender
{
    zipCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:zipText.text];
    [zipText setText:zipCode];
    NSUserDefaults *zipDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [zipDefault setObject:zipCode forKey:@"ZipCode"];
}
```

Comment: As long as you get a complete NSString from your graphic component bind to the saveZip IBAction, I don't understand why you use the initWithFormat initializer. Why not simply initWithString ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use string **literal** for format in `initWithFormat:` method, not a string so your call should be corrected to:

```
zipCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", zipText.text];
```

But in your example you don't need that method at all as you actually don't change the string, so next 'fix step" may be

```
zipCode = [zipText.text copy];
```

But that also leaves one problem unsolved - your previous zipCode value won't be deallocated and will just leak. If zipCode is an instance variable in your class declare a property for it:

```
// Class interface
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *zipCode;
// Class implementation
@synthesize zipCode;
```

That way you  let compiler **automatically** synthesize setter and getter methods for you variable that will handle memory management for you.So now to change your iVar value you can use property:

```
self.zipCode = zipText.text;
```

P.S. and finally - don't forget to release your zipCode in `dealloc` method to avoid memory leaks

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Whew! The bleeding eyeballs have stopped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`initWithFormat:` expects a format string followed by a list of arguments that correspond to the format specifiers in your string.  For example:

```
NSString *city = @"East Aurora";
NSString *state = @"NY";
NSInteger numericZip = 14052;
NSString *lastLineOfAddress = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %d", city, state, numericZip];
```

In this example, `lastLineOfAddress` will reference the string `@"East Aurora, NY 14052"`.  There are three format specifiers in the format string.  The first two format specifiers are `%@`, which can be a placeholder for any object type.  `%d` is a placeholder for a decimal integer value.  The three parameters that follow the format string correspond to these three format specifiers.

(I see that someone else has now posted a solid answer to your question, so I'll cut off my answer here.)